# Parsing through data from an old mac text editor. (Recovering data from a Mac floppy.)

Tags: software-recommendation, word-processor, floppy

I've been tasked with the job of recovering the text of a book stored on a 3.5'' floppy disk. From what I can tell, the book was stored on the disk using a Mac sometime in the 1990s.

I tried simply reading the disk on my older Windows machine, but I received the error: "The disk is not formatted". I tried using several file recovery programs, but they mostly indicated that the disk was probably corrupt.

However, I was able to create an .IMA disk image file in Windows. I transferred this file to my newer PC and opened it was a text editor. It seems that the text of the book is intact, but it is mixed in with many formatting characters that I think are an artifact of some old Mac word processor. For example I think `Ü ┐Ü` represents a line break.

Is there any (PC) software I can use to parse out all of theses formatting symbols? Or better yet, is there software that could perhaps understand the original format that the book was written in? Unfortunately I do not have a single file, instead it's trapped in a disk image. (And I am not able to extract the disk image because the disk is "corrupt.") I could manually go through and edit the text, but this would be extremely time consuming, considering that the book is ~1 MB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best guess with no additional information would be that it is a ClarisWorks file.

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) should be able to open it - the translation is apparently not perfect, but might be good enough to work with.

Idea garnered from [How to open your ClarisWorks files for a stroll down memory lane](http://www.macworld.com/article/2848770/how-to-open-your-clarisworks-documents-for-a-stroll-down-memory-lane.html)

There's also the possibility of extracting the files directly from the floppy to Windows using [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/) or even [MacDisk](http://www.macdisk.com/mden.php) (though that looks pretty old) rather than trying to pick bits out of a WinImage file.